# Private variables in the @implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it a good practice to declare some private element in the .m, instead of doing a @property on the .h?

And, if it's OK, are these element considered as `weak`?

Example: (in the top of .m)

```
   @implementation ParticipantMaterials{
        UIImageView *imgBackground;
        UILabel *lblTitle;
        UITableView *tvTableContent;
        NSMutableDictionary *tblElements;
    }
```

Comment: 1. Why the `xcode` tag? 2. *What?*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When declaring variables in the `@implementation` region, you are declaring instance variables, not properties. You do not `@synthesize` ivars. If you want to declare private properties hidden from the public .h file, you can create them like so:

```
@interface ParticipantMaterials ()

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger uintProp;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* strProp;

@end
```

This is called a class extension.

Instance variables are considered `strong` by default, unless you specify the `__weak` type modifier.

Comment: ok, so(for private and in .m)
     @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* strProp;

was same as 

     NSString* strProp;

Comment: Yes, both would be strong.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to declare private variables, any of these declarations will do:

```
@interface Animal : NSObject {
    @private
    NSObject *iPrivate;
}
@end


@interface Animal(){
    @public
    NSString *iPrivate2;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSObject *iPrivate3;
@end

@implementation Animal {
    @public
    NSString *iPrivate4;
}
@end
```

I added the @public to point out that it makes no difference. All of those variables are equally private, and if you attempt to set them from a subclass or a different class, it will result in a `compiler error: undeclared identifier` or, in the first case `compiler error: variable is private`.

All object variables under ARC are strong by default, so you can omit `strong` from the @property if you like.

Variables in Objective-C are not 100% private. You can get/set them from anywhere using the runtime functions `class_getInstanceVariable` and `object_getIvar`.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to have as little in the .h file as possible. So yes, it is good practice to have private ivars and private properties declared in the .m file.

The .h file should only have truly public declarations.

Example:

SomeClass.h:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject <NSCoding> // publicly state conformance to NSCoding

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *publicProperty;

- (void)somePublicMethod;

@end
```

SomeClass.m

```
@interface SomeClass () <UIAlertViewDelegate> // implementation detail

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL privateProperty;

@end

@implementation SomeClass {
    UIAlertView *_privateAlert; // private ivar
}

// all the methods

@end
```

All of this takes advantage of the modern Objective-C compiler. No need for explicit `@synthesize` lines (though they can still be used if appropriate). No need to declare ivars for each property (though they can be if appropriate).

Note that under ARC, ivars and local variables are `strong`, not `weak`.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to notice that on a 64bit architecture, llvm compiler reserve memory  for iVar declared in a @property, since Obj-C 2.0 and intel 64bit CPU, I don't specify my iVars any more.

The OOP paradigm specify that by default, all implemented iVars are **private**

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface PassedAndCorrectTableVC ()
{
NSMutableArray *arrPassesdListName;

NSMutableArray *arrCorrectListNmae;

NSMutableArray *arrTotalName;
}
@end
```